# Why symbols are not loaded for debugging?

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg, dump, debug-symbols

I used Task Manager to create process dump. Copied pdb,.exe,.cpp(source file) and dump in one folder.

When I open crash dump and use `!analyze -v` command in WinDbg, it gives following errors/warnings.

```
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Project1.exe
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for Project1.exe
```

Symbol path is set to,

> http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

When I have source, exe and .pdb why I am not able to load symbols in WinDbg?

Comment: enable noisy symbol loading with !sym noisy it will output where it is looking for the symbols and why symbol loading fails

Comment: From WinDbg you can set the symbol path using the gui: 'File->Symbol Search Path' or 'ctrl+s'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if .pdb’s are in the same folder as the dump, you must include it in the symbol file path,
Try someting like:

```
.sympath c:<Project1>;SRV*C:\WebSymb*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

Same with source, set source path to the folder you have copied into.

The help has a section about symbols. Without symbols, you don’t see source either.